# Apple Developer - What is the 'Fonts' Capability under Register an App ID for?

Tags: ios, app-id, apple-developer

I need to register an App ID in my Apple Developer account and saw under the 'Capabilities' section 'Fonts'. Which I found [on](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev21218dfd6) means 'Fonts: Font Installation allows your app, with user permission, to install and use custom fonts."

I ticked that box thinking that it's related to using custom fonts in my app but got a warning message in Xcode:

**'Waring: Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *My Bundle ID* for *MyAppName* contains entitlements that aren't in the entitlements file: com.apple.developer.user-fonts. To use these entitlements, add them to your entitlements file. Otherwise, remove unused entitlements from your provisioning profile. (in target *MyAppName*).'**

The worse thing is after I untick the Fonts capabilities box in order to get rid of the warning, a modal says **'Modify App Capabilities: Adding or removing any capabilities will invalidate any provisioning profiles that include this App ID and they must be regenerated for future use.'**

After watching this [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/227/), I think 'Fonts' under 'Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles' > 'Capabilities' is for 'Ability to register fonts system-wide'. Whatever that means...

'Adding a custom font to your app' page but doesn't mention the 'Fonts' under 'Capabilities' when Register an App ID.
[Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app)

I think the Fonts capabilities are new and that's why their documentation is inconsistent. Does anyone know in what circumstances do you need to tick that Fonts capabilities box and how to use it?

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to share fonts with other apps? Could you provide a code example? I'm in trouble like you were [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74572097/how-can-i-share-my-apps-font-list-with-ios?noredirect=1#comment131638821_74572097)

Comment: Hi @Lorenzo97Ben, my use case was different to yours. I didn't need to turn font capability on at all so don't have code to share. Have you seen https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/3227897-ctfontmanagerregisterfonturls?changes=_7 ? It has some code example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Does anyone know in what circumstances do you need to tick that Fonts capabilities box and how to use it?

Yes, new in iOS 13 your app can include fonts and can make them available to all the user’s apps by calling  CTFontManagerRegisterFontURLs. This is called installing fonts. You need the capability to do that. The capability is explained at 5:46 of the video you cited in your question. Watch the video, it explains all about this.

You do not need the entitlement merely to include and use fonts within your own app.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Do you know how to regenerate a provisioning profile? Does it mean I need to delete and re-add that identifier? I tried but it didn't let me because it's linked to an app in the App Store. Now I'm stuck with that warning message and worry about I might lose the app name if I mess around deleting things.

Comment: It doesn’t affect the app that’s already in the store. It affects building going forward. See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1878/_index.html

Comment: The doc helps, now that I see the provisional profiles are in https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/list, but I haven't generated any provisional profiles yet. I can get rid of the warning message by clicking in Xcode: Product > Clean Build Folder and the warning only comes back if I plug in my phone to build and run the app. The warning doesn't appear if I build in a simulator device. Makes me wonder if it's something I can ignore...

Comment: Well, if you're using manual provisioning for this project, I would just go ahead and create the new provisioning profile. However I'd like to suggest that we are now off topic. The question was what this entitlement / capability is for, and we have settled that. The question of what to do if you accidentally turn on an capability you don't need for an app that is already in the store is a completely different issue. :)

Comment: Just found this page https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev037e8f543?sub=devfdb3dfeed about Edit, download, or delete provisioning profiles.

Answer (score 3):

Since iOS 13, apps can make use of a `Fonts` entitlement, with a sub option '**Use Installed Fonts**' to use custom fonts installed by special font provider apps. Font provider apps make use of the same entitlement, but with sub option **'Install Fonts**'. Examples of such apps are *CreativeCloud* from Adobe and *MyFonts* from MonoType.

You only need to add the `Fonts` entitlement to your app, if you want to use fonts installed by said font provider apps, or if you are developing a font provider app yourself.