# How can I share my app's font list with iOS

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, fonts

I had a custom font created and I'm using it in my application built in swiftui.

Since they liked the font, I would like to use it not only in the application but also on all the iPhones and iPads that have my application installed. I searched the internet a bit and came up with this:

- The font must be in a folder inside the project;
- I have to register the font in "Fonts provide by application";
- In "Capabilities" add "Fonts" and activate the two items: **Install Fonts** and **Use Installed Fonts**;
- If my application is uninstalled, the font will automatically no longer be available to the operating system;

Most importantly I understood that I have to use this class CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont.
But I don't understand how to use it.

Many tutorials show how to use a font in your application but none ever share the imported fonts with the device.

How can I go on? I also searched this site but couldn't find anything.
Please don't report it as a DUPLICATE POST

Comment: Apple has a whole presentation on this. See https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/227/

Comment: I saw that video but I don't know how to continue.  One question, do I need to have an active Apple Developer profile?  I haven't renewed it, I don't think this is the problem right?  On the simulator it should still go or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. I hope it is useful to others.

```
var fontUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyCustomFont", withExtension: "ttf")
//I apply the registration
registerFont(fontUrl: fontUrl!)
.....

private func registerFont(fontUrl : URL){
    CTFontManagerRegisterFontURLs([fontUrl] as CFArray, .persistent, true) { (errors, done) -> Bool in
            if(done) {
                print("Done")
            }
            print(errors as Array)
            return true
        }
}
```

When you run the application you will get the pop up to install the font.

At this point: **Settings** > **General** > **Font**
You will find the font